# backbone relational variable parent

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations, backbone-relational

I'm looking to properly architect my backbone models using backbone relational and wanted to know if this is the proper way to do this. I want to have a model `Reviewable` that can either have a parent of Photo or Video. Essentially each photo or video can have many reviews.

[image]

Is this the right way to structure this?

```
Photo = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    relations: [
        {
            type: Backbone.HasOne,
            key: 'reviewable',
            relatedModel: 'Reviewable',
            reverseRelation: 
            {
                key: 'parent',
                includeInJSON: 'id'
            }
        }
    ]
});

Video = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    relations: [
        {
            type: Backbone.HasOne,
            key: 'reviewable',
            relatedModel: 'Reviewable',
            reverseRelation: 
            {
                key: 'parent',
                includeInJSON: 'id'
            }
        }
    ]
});

Reviewable = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    relations: [
    {
        type: Backbone.HasMany,
        key: 'reviews',
        relatedModel: 'Review',
        collectionType: 'ReviewCollection',
        reverseRelation: {
            key: 'parent',
            includeInJSON: 'id'
        }
    }
    ]
});

Review = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
});

ReviewCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Review
});
```

**EDIT**

```
Photo = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
});

Video = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
});

Reviewable = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
     subModelTypes: {
        'photo': 'Photo',
        'video': 'Video'
    },
    relations: [
    {
        type: Backbone.HasMany,
        key: 'reviews',
        relatedModel: 'Review',
        collectionType: 'ReviewCollection',
        reverseRelation: {
            key: 'parent',
            includeInJSON: 'id'
        }
    }
    ]
});

Review = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
});

ReviewCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Review
});
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Backbone-relational but it conceptually it seems like Photo and Video are *kinds* of Reviewables, not things that *have* Reviewables. Glancing at the Backbone-relational docs it seems like Photo and Video would work well as "sub-models" of Reviewable. The docs under [`subModelTypes`](http://backbonerelational.org/#RelationalModel-subModelTypes) give an example where Primate and Carnivore are sub-models of Animal, which seems analogous.

Comment: Ah I see thanks for taking a look. So is that all I would be missing you think? Just add the subModelTypes for Reviewable and remove the relations for Video and Photo? See edit

Comment: I believe Photo and Video need to extend Reviewable (e.g. `Photo = Reviewable.extend()`). Like I said, though, I'm not familiar with Backbone-relational. Your reading of the docs is probably as good as mine.